# Importing txt file in SAS

Tags: import, sas, txt

I tried to import text file in `sas` with the following code

```
PROC IMPORT DATAFILE= '/home/u44418748/MSc Biostatistics with SAS/Datasets/school.txt' 
OUT= outdata 
DBMS=dlm 
REPLACE; 
delimiter='09'x;
GETNAMES=YES; 
RUN;
```

But I am getting import unsuccessful because text file has period for missing data

this is  what i got in `SAS` log

```
NOTE: Invalid data for class_size in line 455 16-17.
 
 455 CHAR  454.34.8.32.17.NA.23.125.12.188 31
     ZONE  3330330303303304403323330332333
     NUMR  454934989329179E1923E125912E188
 sl_no=454 school=34 iq=8 test=32 ses=17 class_size=. meanses=23.125 meaniq=12.188 _ERROR_=1 _N_=454
```

how can load this text file in `SAS`

Comment: Looks like you did import the file successfully. Assuming that NA in the numeric field CLASS_SIZE was meant to mean that the size of that class was unknown then setting the value to missing is probably what you wanted to have happen.

Answer (score 1):

Did you create that text file from R?  That package has a nasty habit of putting text values of NA for numeric values into text files.  If you are the one that created the file the you might check if the system you are using has a way to not put the NA into the file to begin with.  In a delimited file missing values are normally represented by having nothing for the field. So the delimiters are right next to each other.  For SAS you can use a period to represent a missing value.

I wouldn't bother to use PROC IMPORT to read a delimited file.  Just write a data step to read the file.  Since it looks like your file only has six variables and they are all numeric the code is trivial.

```
data outdata;
   infile '/home/u44418748/MSc Biostatistics with SAS/Datasets/school.txt' 
     dsd dlm='09'x firstobs=2 truncover
   ;
   input sl_no school iq test ses class_size meanses meaniq ;
run;
```

One way to deal with the NA text in the input file is to replace them with periods.  Since all of the fields are numeric you can do that easily because you don't have to worry about replacing real text that just happens to have the letter A after the letter N.  Here is trick using the `_INFILE_` automatic variable that you can use to make the change on the fly while reading the file.

```
data outdata;
   infile '/home/u44418748/MSc Biostatistics with SAS/Datasets/school.txt' 
     dsd dlm='09'x firstobs=2 truncover
   ;
   input @;
   _infile_=tranwrd(_infile_,'NA','.');
   input sl_no school iq test ses class_size meanses meaniq ;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the `NOTE:` because of the `NA` value in the `class_size` field.

What you presume are periods (`.`) are actually tabs (hex code `09`).  Look under the period to confirm, the `ZONE` is `0` and `NUMR` `9`. `09` is the tab character.

`Proc IMPORT` guesses each fields data type based on looking at the first few rows (default is 20 rows) of a  text file.  Your file contained only numbers the 20 rows, so the procedure guessed `class_size` was numeric.

There a couple of courses of action.

- Do nothing.  Read your log `NOTES` and know the places where `NA` occurred you will have a missing value in your data set.
- *or,*
  Read the file as-is, but add `GUESSINGROWS=MAX;` statement to your import code

  - The *mixed data type* column `class_size` will be guessed as character and you might have to do another step to convert the values to numeric (a step in which the non-digit values get converted to missing values)
- *or*,
    Edit the text file replacing all the `NA` with a period (`.`).  The dot marks a missing value during IMPORT.  The IMPORT step will have no incongruities to LOG about.

**Converting a field**

```
PROC IMPORT DATAFILE= '/home/u44418748/MSc Biostatistics with SAS/Datasets/school.txt'
  DBMS=dlm REPLACE OUT=work.outdata;

  delimiter='09'x;
  GETNAMES=YES; 
  GUESSINGROWS=MAX;
RUN;

data want;
  set outdata (rename=(class_size=class_size_char));
  class_size = input (class_size_char, ?? best12.);
  drop class_size_char;
run;
```